# Find volume of body given by $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq a^2$ and $x^2+y^2 \geq a(a-2z)$, $a>0$. Is this answer right? What are mistakes in my solution?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, solution-verification

It appears to be an upside-down 'bowl', cut out of a sphere by a paraboloid. Moving to cylindrical coordinates,
\begin{align}
4 \int_0^{\pi/2}\ d\phi \int_{0}^{a}\   r \ dr \int_{(a^2-r^2)/2a}^{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}} \ dz
&=
4 \int_0^{\pi/2}\ d\phi \int_{0}^{a}\ \left( \frac{a^2-r^2}{2}-\frac{(a^2-r^2)^2}{2a\cdot\ 2a\cdot2} \right) r \ dr 
\\ \ \\
&=
2 \int_0^{\pi/2}\ d\phi \int_{0}^{a}\ \left( \frac{a^2-r^2}{1}-\frac{(a^2-r^2)^2}{4a^2} \right) r \ dr 
\\ \ \\
&=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\ d\phi \int_{0}^{a}\ \left( \frac{3a^2}{2}r-r^3-\frac{r^5}{2a^2} \right)\ dr 
\\ \ \\
&=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\   \frac{3a^2}{2}\cdot \frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a^4}{4}-\frac{1}{2a^2}\cdot\frac{a^6}{6} \ d\phi
\\ \ \\
&=
\frac{5\pi a^4}{24}
\end{align}

Was this correct? If not, where?

I'd also love to see alternative ways of doing this.

Comment: For future reference, this bowl is a 3D object, so you should expect the answer to be proportional to $a^3.$ Martin already fixed the mistake, but it is easier to fix the mistake and know that you have fixed it when you have an idea of how the answer should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your setup is the canonical one, with the exception of taking $0\leq \phi\leq \pi/2$ and then multiplying by $4$: you could have just integrated from $0$ to $2\pi$.
- You are assuming that $a>0$, which is probably the case but you don't say.
- From the first to the second line: instead of $\sqrt{a^2-r^2}-\frac{a^2-r^2}{2a}$ you wrote $\frac{a^2-r^2}2-\frac{(a^2-r^2)^2}{2a\cdot2a\cdot2}$. I can't imagine why. That's where things derail.

What you should have done: 
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a \int_{\frac{a^2-r^2}{2a}}^{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}\,1\,dz\,r\,dr\,d\theta
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a\left({\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}-{\frac{a^2-r^2}{2a}}\right)\,r\,dr\,d\theta\\ \ \\
&={2\pi}\int_0^a\left({\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}-{\frac{a^2-r^2}{2a}}\right)\,r\,dr\\ \ \\
&={2\pi}\left.\vphantom{\int}\left(-\frac23(a^2-r^2)^{3/2}+\frac{(a^2-r^2)^2}{4a}\right)\right|_0^a\\\ \ \\
&=2\pi\,\left(\frac13(a^2)^{3/2}-\frac{(a^2)^2}{8a}\right)\\ \ \\
&=\frac{5\pi a^3}{12}
\end{align}

As a way to confirm the result, if you   calculate the bottom half, the limits of the inner integral would have been
$$
\int_{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}^{\frac{a^2-r^2}{2a}},
$$
and a very similar calculation as above yields $\frac{11\pi a^3}{12}$. Not surprisingly, if you add both volumes you get 
$$
\frac{5\pi a^3}{12}+\frac{11\pi a^3}{12}=\frac{16\pi a^3}{12}=\frac{4\pi a^3}3, 
$$
the volume of the whole interior of the sphere.

Comment: Thank you very much. The fourth bullet: a silly algebraic mistake on my part, I was already thinking antiderivative of $r$. Could you please explain why is the problem not entirely well-defined? Doesn't the inequality $x^2+y^2 \geq a(a-2z)$ tells to only look at the top part?

Comment: Yes, if $a>0$ you are right. I'll delete that.

Comment: (Added $a>0$ at the question title for clarity).